# Promesas con NodeJS

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, promesas

Tengo un array de tiendas el cual mediante promesas trato de obtener el horario de cada una, pero en algunos casos obtengo el siguiente error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'length' of undefined
>       at controlar_horario (linea de codigo 452:41)
>       at Promise.all.then.catch.err (linea de codigo 426:15)

Este es mi codigo:

```
for (var i =0; i < datosRes.tiendas.length; i++){
  horarios.push(GetHorarios(datosRes.tiendas, i))
}
Promise.all(horarios).then(response => {
  for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
    if(response[i].length > 0){
      datosRes.tiendas[i].hay_horario = true;
      for(var j=0;j<response[i].length;j++){
        if(datosRes.tiendas[i].id == response[i][j].id_tienda_horario){
          datosRes.tiendas[i].listaHorarios = response[i][j];
        }
      }
    }else{
      datosRes.tiendas[i].hay_horario = false;
    }
  }
  eq.local = data;
}).catch(err => {
  controlar_horario(datosRes, res)//esta es la linea 426
})

function GetHorarios(tiendas, i){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var hoy = moment().format("d")
    var id_tienda = tienda[i].id;
    bd_getHorario.getHorarioPorDia(id_tienda, hoy,function(error, data){
      if(error || data.error){
        errorDB = {"error_log": error, "error_data": data.error};
        reject(errorDB)
      }else{
        resolve(data)
      }
    })
  })
}

function controlar_horario(datosRes, res){
  for(var i =0; i < datosRes.tiendas.length; i++){ //esta es la linea 452
    if(datosRes.tiendas[i].hay_horario){
      //controlar horarios .....
    }else{
      //no hay horario .....
    }
  return res.json(200,{"datos":datosRes});
  }
}
```

En realidad nose porque me da ese error, estaria agradecido por su ayuda

Comment: Parece ser que dentro de la promesa el response o uno de los hijos sea undefined y por eso te salta ese error. Te crecomiendo que uses el console.log(response); para ver en consola lo que tiene esa variable.

Comment: datosRes, en el catch no tienes nada!!! obviamente es una variable en undefined , cuando intentas acceder  `datosRes.tiendas` es undefined y agregale el .length , undefined no tiene la funcion length , deberias preguntarte porque esta entrando en el catch

Comment: por cierto las promesas son en JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Sólo como nota preliminar, en tu función `controlar_horario` tienes un parámetro `datosRes`, pero en el ámbito superior esa variable ya existe, por lo cual estás haciendo `shadowing` de la variable original. Eso es una mala práctica pero no explica el problema en cuestión.

Vamos al grano. El error dice que en la función

```
function controlar_horario(datosRes, res){

}
```

El parámetro `datosRes` no tiene una propiedad `tiendas` por lo que evaluar `datosRes.tiendas.length` genera un error.

El error es gatillado cuando en el bloque `catch` llamas a

```
}).catch(err => {
  controlar_horario(datosRes, res);
})
```

Pero si entró en el bloque catch, es porque hay un error previo que **no estás logueando ni imprimiendo en ninguna parte**. Yo empezaría por averiguar qué es lo que te hace entrar en el catch.

Sabiendo que hay un error más arriba, éste debiera estar dentro de una de las promesas que metiste en `horarios` o bien en lo que haces dentro del `then` luego de `Promise.all`.

Mirando lo que metes en  `horarios` veo que la definición de `GetHorarios` es:

```
function GetHorarios(tiendas, i){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var hoy = moment().format("d")
    var id_tienda = tienda[i].id;
    bd_getHorario.getHorarioPorDia(id_tienda, hoy,function(error, data){
      if(error || data.error){
        errorDB = {"error_log": error, "error_data": data.error};
        reject(errorDB)
      }else{
        resolve(data)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Yo por lo menos veo que le pasas un parámetro `tiendas` y luego declaras que `var id_tienda = tienda[i].id;` ¿Será que el error está en no haber usado el plural?

Tengo que comentar además que te estás dando más vueltas que las necesarias. Podrías declarar `GetHorarios` como:

```
function GetHorarios(tienda){
  ...
}
```

Y olvidarte del índice, el cual manejarías en el primer bucle haciendo:

```
for (var i =0; i < datosRes.tiendas.length; i++){
  horarios.push(GetHorarios(datosRes.tiendas[i]))
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respues @amenadiel perdon si esta en plural, al momento de escribir la pregunta se me ha borrado